# Java MongoDB driver: How to update all Documents in Collection?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

The following code allows us to update all documents in `customerDetail` collection where `customer_user_id` is `1`:

```
db.getCollection("customerDetail")
        .updateMany(Filters.eq("customer_user_id", 1),
                Updates.combine(
                        Updates.set("birth_year", "birth_year"),
                        Updates.set("country", "country")
                ));
```

but I need to update **ALL** documents in the collection, so I need to find a way how to ask Java Driver do not apply any filters to update query, but as I can see for `updateMany` method `Filter` is a mandatory attribute and I can't just pass `null`.

So how can I update all documents?

Comment: Why not send `new Document()` as the first argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option which I use frequently

```
mongoCollectionObject
        .updateMany(new Document(), //
                new Document("$set"
                        new Document("birth_year", "birth_year")
                        .append("country", "country")
                ));
```

First one is the condition - as it is empty - equivalent to `{}` - means all documents

second one is the document to be set for all matching documents